# RoR - add method to dependent collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, dependencies

There is two classes(`Order`, `Cart`), that have the same dependent another class (`LineItem`) with `has_many` association.

I can fetch the records like `items = @order.line_items`, and I want to add a method on that collection to be able to count `items.total_price` for example on both `Cart` and `Order`.

I know about something like `@order.line_items.to_a.sum(&:method)`, but it's a bit complicated.

For now I have identical methods in both classes, and I want to DRY it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is `Module` that will implement that behaviour.

In your `app/models/concerns` folder create file called `priceable.rb`

and put this code inside

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Priceable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :line_items
  end
  # instance methods on object that includes this module
  def total_price
    #logic
  end

  # class methods for class that will include module
  module ClassMethods

    # define class methods
  end
end
```

In your `model` `order` insert next line of code, and in `cart` model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base    
    include Priceable
    # remove from here has_many :line_items
    # it has been moved to the module
    ...
end
```

Comment: If you do not like name for the module change it accordingly, but try to name it as behaviour it give to the class that includes it